# Creating a static search/filter panel in Geocortex html5 Viewer

Tags: filter, geocortex, workflow

Is there a way to create a static filter panel that filters on current results or map extent?
e.g. after performing an address search, to filter on neighbouring property attribute details (data linked by SQL database).

The filter on the toolbar will not work as layer fields are hidden to read from the datalink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a workflow.
 1. Get current extents  -or-  get Selected items
 2. extract whatever field you need to perform your post-query (PropertyID that exists in another databse)
 3. Display the results, either by popping up a dialog box showing text,  or drawing some polygons on the map (or both)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Do you know if there's a way to have the workflow permanently docked to the side without having to call the workflow each time?